# Audio plays, but I cannot see any animation

Tags: animation, audio

Ok, so I downloaded blender on steam a few days ago and downloaded a template file for a Youtube intro. When I opened the file with the blender exe that I use to launch blender, blender opens up and if I start the animation, I can hear the music but I cannot see any animation. When I click render I get the message: Cannot open or start AVI Movie file

I tried installing blender from the website rather than steam, I've tried different templates. I have no idea what to do. Maybe I'm being really stupid because I've never really used blender but if anyone can help I would be very grateful.

If you need extra information please ask, I'm on a windows 10 HP Netbook with a Radeon graphics card

Comment: Please upload the blend file.

Comment: Is it possible that the directory Blender is trying to write the file to doesn't exist?

Comment: Could be that the youtube intro template expects some video file/url, but it isn't available, atm?

Comment: http://jmp.sh/JMUEEgq